# Getting file back from CollectionFS with Angular-Meteor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, meteor, angular-meteor, collectionfs

I'm pretty new with programming. I'm learning how to use CollectionFS with Angular, but cant get the files back from DB. Here is my code:

**Html:**

```
 <body>
  <div class="container" ng-app="upload">
    <div ng-controller="uploadCtrl">
      <form id="uploadForm" >
        <input type="file" id="file">
        <button ng-click="uploadPhoto()">Pobierz</button>
      </form>
      <ul>
        <li  ng-repeat="zdjecie in zdjecia">
            <img ng-src="{{ zdjecie.url }}" />
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

**angular:**

```
angular.module('upload', ['angular-meteor']);

angular.module('upload').controller('uploadCtrl', ['$scope', '$meteor',
  function ($scope, $meteor) {

    $scope.zdjecia = $meteor.collectionFS(Zdjecia, false, Zdjecia);
    var fileInput = document.getElementById('file');

    $scope.uploadPhoto = function () {
    var file = fileInput.files[0];
    $scope.zdjecia.save(file);
  };
}]);
```

**backend:**

```
Zdjecia = new FS.Collection("zdjecia", {
  stores: [
    new FS.Store.FileSystem("zdjecia"), { path : '~/zdjecia'}
  ]
});

if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Zdjecia.allow({
    insert: function () {
      return true;
    }
  });
}
```

I really can't get, how to grab a file back from the database, they also ain’t appear in the path folder.

Comment: Tested it, but ran into the same problem. I've used the GridFS implementation and the files do get saved correctly (so it appears). What's interesting is that if you do a forEach() on the Meteor collection, you'll see that the files are available on the client (as FS.File objects), they just don't show up in the UI.

Comment: You have a 3rd argument in your $meteor.collectionFS that shouldn't be there: `$meteor.collectionFS(Zdjecia, false)`